# SQL query to count unique occurances in data using a 2 table union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:
ClosedClaims - This table contains dozens of fields, the most important are Spare (the ID of the first person to touch the claim), SpareFinished (the date they opened it) and Claim_ID (the ID of the claim).

tblAuditing - This table keeps an audit trail of the people who touch the claim, and contains only three fields; Spare (the ID of the person who touched it), SpareFinished (the date they touched it) and Claim_ID (the ID of the claim touched).

PROC_LIST - This table contains a list of User IDs, their Admin Levels and their full name.

I'm trying to create a query that will give me everyone's name, and the number of claims they've touched.  If they touched a claim more than once, I only want that claim ID to be counted once.  I've got this SQL string:

```
Select PROC_NM as 'Agent Name', AdminLevel as Role, Count(Claim_ID) as 'Count of Claims Reviewed', Spare as AgentID 
from (SELECT DISTINCT Spare, SpareFinished, CLAIM_ID FROM ClosedClaims_MERGE
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Spare, SpareFinished, CLAIM_ID FROM tblAuditing) CCM 
LEFT JOIN PROC_LIST PL ON CCM.Spare = PL.LOGIN 
WHERE CCM.SpareFinished >= '1/1/2013' AND CCM.SpareFinished <= '11/18/2013' 
GROUP BY Spare, PROC_NM, AdminLevel 
ORDER BY Count(Claim_ID) DESC
```

Obviously, because I have the date field in the FROM clause (SpareFinished), it's going to count multiple touches to the same claim.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, as I need to keep SpareFinished in the SQL since the users will be choosing a date range from a form (hence my "WHERE" clause).

My data would look something like this:
+++ ClosedClaims +++

```
Claim_ID       Spare       SpareFinished
123456         CC235        1/1/2013
123457         CC201        6/1/2013
```

+++ tblAuditing +++

```
Claim_ID       Spare       SpareFinished
123456         CC212        4/1/2013
123456         CC201        2/1/2013
123456         CC212        3/1/2013
123456         CC203        2/10/2013
123456         CC201        1/1/2013
123457         CC201        1/7/2013
123457         CC212        3/1/2013
```

+++ PROC_LIST +++

```
AdminLevel     LOGIN        PROC_NM
Senior         CC235        Jim Thomas
Senior         CC201        Sue Schmidt
Junior         CC212        Julie Lawrence
Junior         CC203        Bob Hurley
```

In this case, my output should look something like:

```
Agent Name         Role     Count Of Claims Reviewed     AgentID
Jim Thomas         Senior   1                            CC235
Sue Schmidt        Senior   2                            CC201
Julie Lawrence     Junior   2                            CC212
Bob Hurley         Junior   1                            CC203
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly , I believe that Count(distinct Claim_ID) should work.

Comment: Where's the "That Was Easy!" button?  :o)